# What is the difference between physical level and internal level of a database according to ANSI/SPARC?

Tags: database-theory, databases

According to ANSI/SPARC model a database consists of three (or four?) levels. These are internal (and/or physical?), conceptual and external levels.

Most information resources say like physical and internal levels are the same, i.e. these are two alternative names for the same actual level. But my tutors' lecture material say that these are two different levels, though no convincing arguments are provided.

So where is the truth and what is it? Or did I messed up something?

Comment: Why don't you cite the resources here?

Comment: I have edited my question. The only resource that says that internal and physical levels differs is my tutors' lecture materials. They are not in English, but in my native language. That's why I thought there was no sense to cite it.

Comment: You should ask your tutors. We can't second-guess their mind.

Comment: The Book, Database System written by Thomas Connolly and Carolyn Begg says so.(Physsical Layer is Below Internal Level) But i am confused too in this.